# How to disable AllUsers and Guests from viewing my project

Tags: youtrack

I just changed my youtrack license plan to `3 Users, 1 private Project` and therefore wanted to make my project private.

Within the `Access` menu I only see this:

[image]

But I can not find away to actually disable `guest` or `All Users` from viewing my projects issues in the Issues menu and so on.

How can I configure this?

Comment: I would try https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545659-How-to-Make-a-Project-Private

Comment: `Ensure that 'All users' group does not have permissions to view the project.` As you can see in my screenshot I am not able to change anything for `All Users` since there isn't any checkbox

Comment: This must be a project access tab. Global roles can only be revoked from All Users group via Groups > All Users > Roles tab.

Comment: thx that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jk1
Told to check out  Groups > All Users > Roles tab. That was the solution